# How to dynamically assign method to button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my IOS app I have a button that the user can assign a custom action to, but I don't know what the best way is to dynamically set actions to the button. My first idea was to change the [sender tag] of the button, and then after being pressed it will read a series of "if" statements that say "if (sender tag=1){then do this} if(sender tag=2){then do this}, and so on." But the problem with this is that i will have thousands of possible actions, so if someone chooses an action who's sender tag is 2000, then the method will have to read through every single question before it reads the "if (sender tag=2000)", which is a waste of time. How can I dynamically set an action to a Button?

Comment: What is the actual app that you are trying to create. If you have that many possible things then it sounds like a table view might be better etc... Explain what the view is trying to do. There will be a better way of doing this.

Comment: You can use `class_addMethod` to add a method to your class at runtime based on what the user is doing ([reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod)) and then when the button is pressed use `performSelector:` to call your dynamically added method ([reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:))

Comment: well I used a button as an example in my description, but similar to how the action will be customized, the event causing the action will be customizable as well. This customizable situation will be set up by the user, So I can't guess what will be showing on the screen. That's why I want to figure out if I can link methods to events, but also unlink and link new methods to an event during run-time, and if not then is there a work around?

Comment: Thanks Morgan Chen! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options. Buttons support target/action, so you can change the button's action using 
`removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` and `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

Or you could use tags as you say. Tags are numeric, so you could use a switch statement rather than a chain of if/then/else. Better yet, though, would be to use an NSArray of blocks and invoke the appropriate block for the user-selected action.

Example:

In your header:

```
typedef void (^myButtonBlock)(id sender);
```

In your implementation:

```
myButtonBlock aBlock = ^(UIButton *sender) 
{   
  NSLog(@"Button block triggered for button with tag %d", sender.tag); 
}

NSMutableArray *blocksArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[blocksArray addObject: aMethod];
```

Comment: Hmm. I'd recommend using target/action. The buttons already have that support built in. Using blocks involves writing a bunch of new program logic.

Comment: I'm prepared to write all the necessary logic, and I was only using a button as an example, the cause of the event could be anything during runtime. Storing blocks sounds like it fits a few other situations I was unsure about as well.

Comment: What is the specific type of object I have to store a block inside? As a bad example, I was thinking it would look like this: NSBlock *myBlock= { do some line of code..}; I know "NSBlock" is not a real term, I am just wondering if you could refer me to something that explains how to set up and store a block. If not, I can find it somewhere, thanks for all the help!

Comment: A block is an object. You can store blocks in NSArrays just like any other object. Any code that declares a block variable will show you the syntax. As an example, take a look at the definition of 
NSComparator: `typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);` That defines a new type, `NSComparator`. You can define variables of type NSComparator. You can then add them to an array.